# punctuation of "damned if you do and damned if you don't"

Tags: punctuation, quotes, dashes

Personally, I think quotes are best, but lately, I'm hearing that quotes are incorrect and dashes should be used between the words.  What say you?

> damned-if-you-do and damned-if-you-don't

or

> "damned if you do and damned if you don't"

<sub>By the way, I love your website.</sub>

Comment: Those aren’t dashes — they’re hyphens.  **Hyphens are for *joining*, dashes for *separating***.

Comment: @jwpat7 Interesting point; I wonder whether this doesn’t merit a posting on Meta.

Comment: I would only use hyphens when using these phrases as nouns or adjectives, as in *a damned-if-you-do situation*, or *this is a case of damned-if-you-do*. Otherwise I see no reason for the hyphens. Nor do I think the quotation marks would serve any purpose.

Comment: Yes, sorry - - hyphens, for sure. NOT dashes. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: Perhaps examples would help - - which sentence do you think is correct?  
 
 A. Her boyfriend felt he was in a damned-if-I-do, damned-if-I-don't situation.  

 
 
B. Her boyfriend felt he was in a damned if I do, damned if I don't situation.

Answer (score 3):

If "damned if you do and damned if you don't" isn't being used an adjective, don't hyphenate anything.

> This is a tricky situation. You're damned if you do and you're damned if you don't.

If the phrase is being used as an adjective, hyphenate the whole thing.

> This is one of those tricky you're-damned-if-you-do-and-you're-damned-if-you-don't situations.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the mode of usage.

> Tommy said he did it because "I love my spouse".

OTOH, equally comprehensive,

> Tommy said he did it because he is an I-love-my-spouse kind of guy.

Another example,

> She confronted us by saying "Over my dead body."

And equally descriptive,

> We encountered the over-my-dead-body confrontation with her.

Therefore,

> "We are in dire straits here. We are up against a rock and a hard place. Damn if we do and damn if we don't."

We could narrate their experience with,

> They felt they were in a between-a-rock-and-a-hard-place situation and a damn-if-they-do-damn-if-they-don't dilemma.

It depends on whether you are quoting direct speech, or using the phrase as an adjective.

Comment: If you're giving a direct quote, even mistakes should be faithfully reproduced.